# how INSERT works before issuing a COMMIT in Oracle

Tags: oracle, insert, cursor

My question is how oracle treats an INSERT transaction before issuing a COMMIT.

While I am doing an INSERT transaction, will oracle wait until I have inserted all my records within that procedure and then when I issue a COMMIT  statement will the records be saved in a sequence for this transaction?

In the following code, the first insert that is made is the number of rows (metadata) and then the cursor loops and starts inserting the actual data.

Is there a possibility, in one transaction when I call this procedure, first my metadata record is inserted and then some other data (not related to this transaction) be inserted and then rest of my data. So that, the first record and the rest of the records from the loop are not inserted in a Sequence.

```
-- This code belongs to proecdure when ever a user clicks on insert 
-- button from the front end form

DECLARE

    rowcnt NUMBER;

    CURSOR c_get_employ IS
    SELECT EMP.EMPLOYER_ID, EMP.EMPLOYER_NAME, EMP.EMPLOYER_LOCATION
          FROM EMP
            WHERE EMP.EMPLOYER_COUNTRY = 'USA'
    ORDER BY EMP.EMPLOYER_ID;

BEGIN

    Select count(*) 
    INTO rowcnt 
    FROM EMP
    WHERE EMP.EMPLOYER_COUNTRY = 'USA'
    ORDER BY EMP.EMPLOYER_ID;

    -- I want to insert the 'number of employee records' that will be inserted (metadata)

    INSERT INTO EMP_OUTPUT 
        (EMPID, EMPNAME, EMPLOC, ECOUNT)
    VALUES
        (,,,rowcnt);

    -- Then loop through the cursor and start inserting the data
    FOR c_post_employ IN c_get_employ LOOP

        INSERT INTO EMP_OUTPUT 
            (EMPID, EMPNAME, EMPLOC)
        VALUES
            (c_post_employ.EMPLOYER_ID,c_post_employ.EMPLOYER_NAME,c_post_employ.EMPLOYER_LOCATION);

    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single SQL statement if possible.  It will have statement-level read consistency, and will be much faster.

```
insert into emp_output(empid, empname, emploc, ecount)
with employees as
(
    select employer_id, employee_name, employer_location
    from emp
    where employer_country = 'USA'
    order by employer_id    
)
select null, null, null, count(*) from employees
union all
select employer_id, employee_name, employer_location, null from employees;
```

Answer (score 4):

Another transaction can perform inserts concurrently to your transaction, but your transaction won't see them:

- until the other transaction commits (if your transaction is using READ COMMITTED isolation), or
- ever (when using SERIALIZABLE isolation) - you'll need to start another transaction to see them.

Whether this will yield a correct behavior, is for you to decide.

---

Just be careful about `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` - it may not return what you expect. Consider the following scenario:

- The EMP table is initially empty.
- Transaction A starts and inserts a row in EMP, but does not commit.
- Transaction B starts and inserts a row in EMP, but does not commit.
- Transaction A executes `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP` and gets 1 (because it sees its own newly inserted row, but does not see B's newly inserted row since B did not commit yet).
- Transaction B executes `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP` and also gets 1 (for the same reason but in reverse).
- Transaction A inserts 1 into EMP_OUTPUT and commits.
- Transaction B inserts 1 into EMP_OUTPUT and commits (assuming there is no key violation).

So, 1 is inserted despite table actually having 2 rows!

Unfortunately not even Oracle's SERIALIZABLE isolation will save you from this kind of anomaly. Pretty much the only way to guarantee the "correct" result if to [lock the entire table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9015.htm), so no concurrent inserts (or deletes) can occur.

Comment: What if this procedure is run at the end of the day when there is no change to the EMP table. But as part of the daily update process, the data from EMP table is inserted into EMP_OUTPUT table. And there are 2 procedures which run for each country like USA, EU, MEA, AF.......These procedures run independently but update the same table EMP_OUTPUT. This is where my question is.......when I start my insert for USA, I first count the number of rows for USA to be inserted and then immediately insert the actual data. Only after this I issue a final commit. So will this insert be in sequence?

Comment: Did not have enough space..so I am continuing in another comment................So will this insert be in sequence? Will ORACLE first 'gather' all my inserts (metadata and the actual data) for my session/transaction of this procedure and wait for me to issue the COMMIT and then Oracle inserts them 'together' as one batch for one session?

Comment: @user547453 The changes made by a transaction will be "in sequence" from the perspective of _that_ transaction (any given operation will "see" the effects of the preceding operations). As I explained in my answer, they won't necessarily be "in sequence" from the perspective of the whole database, but this won't matter when there is only one transaction at a time. OTOH, _when_ exactly are the changes written to the permanent storage is implementation detail - the only thing client can count on is that transactions are **durable**, i.e. changes are guaranteed to be persistent at COMMIT.

Answer (score 1):

The term you want to google for is "read consistency":

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm

Bottom line:

- As you know, if you rollback, it's as though the inserts "never happened"
- However, other stuff can (and probably did) "happen" in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run in the Serializable Isolation Level:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/consist.htm#BABCJIDI

"Serializable transactions see only those changes that were committed at the time the transaction began, plus those changes made by the transaction itself through INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. Serializable transactions do not experience nonrepeatable reads or phantoms."

Comment: Ok..the scenario is very simple...........I do not commit after the first insert (as indicated in my code) and I still do not commit until I have looped through the cursor and inserted rest of the data. Only when I have no more records to insert..then I issue Commit.

Comment: @user547453 EMP could change between your two reads of EMP without being in serializable.  That would be a nonrepeatable read.

Comment: I get what you are saying. I have a weird business constraint.......................what suppose data in the EMP table does not change for EMP.EMPLOYER_COUNTRY = 'USA' when I call this procedure? But data can change for EMP.EMPLOYER_COUNTRY = 'EU'. The records are different but the table from which the data is retrieved and the table inserted to is the same.  And this is where my point is....will MY data still be insert in sequence or be out of sequence when records for EMP.EMPLOYER_COUNTRY = 'EU' is also inserted at the same time.

Comment: @user547453 I don't see anything in your process which specifies an ordering on the table.  Certainly the two inserts can be going simultaneously, and then commit.  As far as the ordering on the rows, if you were to select the rows without an ORDER BY, there is no requirement for the server to return them in any particular order.  I would also note that your EMP_OUTPUT is storing two different kinds of data, the summary and the detail.  If you want to maintain order, I suggest you assign each batch a batch ID and then a row number within the batch, then when you select, use both of those.